# Cluster web interface on Google Cloud Dataproc

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-dataproc

I try to access to hadoop web interface of my cluser hadoop (on dataproc) and for that i follow this instructions : https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/cluster-web-interfaces

The ssh tunnel is working but i have no connection...

Someone can help me ?

I use Chrome on Windows 10

Adrien

Comment: What command did you use to run a fresh chrome instance pointing at your SSH tunnel proxy, or what steps did you take to configure your existing chrome session to use the proxy?

Comment: I change the target of the shortcut and i try by the console with the same command : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" 
  --proxy-server="socks5://localhost:1080" 
  --host-resolver-rules="MAP * 0.0.0.0 , EXCLUDE localhost" 
  --user-data-dir=/tmp/

Comment: Do you see anything printed out to the console from your long-running SSH tunnel command while accessing your browser?

Comment: No, i have nothing in the console.

Comment: Are you keeping the SSH command running the whole time while trying to access the browser? If the SSH tunnel command terminates for whatever reason then it won't work.

Comment: I think my ssh tunnel works fine, i see it when i sent this command : netstat -tpln | grep ssh

Comment: Finally i allowed port  of my master